# Getting ESC characters and non-printables from UDP socket / buffer

Tags: python, sockets, udp, snmp-trap

I've got a custom script listening on port 161 for UDP packets to come in.
It listens fine, receives the string fine - and when I send a message from a test script (on another box), it displays fine in a log, etc.

I'm gathering the UDP data as follows:

```
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

data contains the string with the information I need.

When performing a tcpdump on the interface that the data is coming in, it looks normal, such as:

```
.1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.1.1.2.12.6 .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.1.1.2.12.6 public "THIS IS THE TRAP" .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.1.1.2.12.6 .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.1.1.2.12.6
```

When I take that incoming data (in python) and print it, or output it to a file, I get a bunch of ESC sequences, or just otherwise unprintable data in the log file.

Everything inside of the Quote is preserved.

I've been able to strip out the ESC sequences and store the 'good stuff' inside of the quotes, but I'm losing my OID's.  It's almost as if python thinks those ascii characters are something else.

I did notice that when trying to save the garbled data, if I change encoding to Latin-1 -- it becomes somewhat readable...but still there's some garbled characters in there.

I've tried to duplicate this matter here at home - but no matter what text I feed through my test.py to the listener on port 161, it comes out just fine and readable.  This was implemented in a test environment at my work.  PS I am not a programmer, but a network guy.

If it matters, the device sending SNMP traps out is an F5 LTM.
I know this is a pretty general question, so I appreciate anyone just taking the time to read my question in its entirety and spend a few minutes thinking about it.

Comment: SNMP is a binary protocol. Why do you expect to be able to print it?

Comment: I'm just trying to receive the traps - If the data comes in and is human readable, can be captured with tcpdump - I guess I just don't understand why when I pull it from the buffer as a string, it becomes garbled.  Thanks.

Comment: It's not human readable, but tcpdump has a parser (or *dissector*) to display various fields in a human-readable form.

Comment: Gotcha - thanks.  I appreciate it.  Gives me something interesting to look into.